# How to use math functions with BigInteger and BigRational

Tags: c#, math

I'm using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` in .Net 4.0 and `BigRational` class from [BCL](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782) to build a math parser/calculator application. The goal is to write a fully functional math parser with support for big numbers ... So I need to use math functions. But unfortunately all System.Math functions return typical data types like float and double so are not very accurate. I need more precision. I dug into microlib.dll but for sine function, just found this:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical, __DynamicallyInvokable]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern double Sin(double a);
```

I know that many math function are not implemented in .Net and come directly from hardware codes. So can I use those function and get high precision or big integers? If not, what's the best way to implement them myself? (performance is also important) Any resources or pointing to the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: decimal type is better then double as precision as far as i know

Comment: Yes, but that's not precise enough either! I need more precision, say about a thousand decimal digits.

Comment: It depends how many digits you need exatly, for speed double would be a better solution.Edit: Cause you wrote you need more precison: Are you aware of the BigDecimal type of the j++ runtime?

Comment: Thanks, But is j++ still supported by Microsoft? If yes, how can I use it in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement them yourself. For trig functions, you will want to read up on [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

However, I doubt this will be practical for thousands of digits. Do you really need that much precision? Generally, if precision like this is really required, you're probably better off not evaluating functions, especially transcendental functions, and working with them symbolically instead.

At the very least, you'll need an arbitrary precision floating point numbers. You could use BigIntegers for this (one for exponent, one for the mantissa). Rational numbers won't be practical.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I'll start writing my class now!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a high precision float class ([HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class)) in MATLAB. And, yes, it IS practical to do the computations asked about here in thousands of digits, at least within limits. Don't expect the result to be lightning fast for numbers that massive.

Here, in well under a second of CPU time, compute sin(0.5) to 2000 decimal digits using [HPF](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class).

```
x = hpf('0.5',2000);
z = sin(x)
z =
0.47942553860420300027328793521557138808180336794060067518861661312553500028781483220963127468434826908613209108450571741781109374860994028278015396204619192460995729393228140053354633818805522859567013569985423363912107172077738015297987137716951517618072114969807370147476869703198703900097339549102989443417733111109673903936124163653480401918346314376284392645260157071283092766006791017533631162287616795734840371866817730333179872034064567347182994506824663612455463453278289361244779536601735462820464717823776898881644512826197840291735466150683689733147287397488788190207928799138423095503817584705030067646428267136203352514539875309014204847017729272889212301417866971280026511717607919387379654420848964303389447566823572876762597714624447000807836928214941991138743810551646471072080462812247422335610868323144633547779337371136437454965479015122728507221582125562761335681781172799521300086891593889552064797344909502979313524137777091507360571026506015248874581726210924892801291055435819896189522803930563792190652684778508854934451273978032859742747386701227727154948654357881637851140514356687525131655792391290065314050467763961605300872097475383191474571466991222453822643126018869834327176291251787779457463370925032134676572752244926564204875494171901976363708322142014379355418299630547673437168013019784069157658698329043158470653971407921567047204742130833307984199944961246141304498844116424471800555566374594078227611966253268668739369977542338090766178818446935337871719545939020589010000184922392803416567433189354514503108047619925727424426280213643488597421990337636199906535549697075412246167977122862009545754093682493517801100883291428841032100118426615836052047298714537824867973933776850058028935197623983399376280971742853670048048344682272994976197375983973258649430222855535025176957323557911906997589014243194056649766589116017811954178461482380269627190632898835306576210057831124120168311609126946042808735584921993653157751619630908157551923919459017792007414

asin(z)
ans =
0.5

asin(z) - x
ans =
3.e-2004
```

I wrote HPF essentially from scratch, without recourse to an existing code like the Java BigDecimal class, which I did test out. In fact, I wrote the entire class several times, once as an overlay on java.math.BigDecimal class. I found I did not like their implementation, so I started over and wrote it myself. You can find details in a .pdf file included in the zip.

Having said all that, I spent literally man-months in that effort, learning various tricks to tease many thousands of digits from a series implementation.

So even if you do use a tool like the java BigDecimal class, you will still probably need to find or build tools to compute special functions on those numbers. This was the part that cost most of my time.

Are such computations, done in thousands of digits, a good use of CPU time? Only you know. Personally, it was a great deal of fun to write a tool like that.